# How to do this length≤1 more than once?

Tags: recursion, scheme, y-combinator, the-little-schemer, anonymous-recursion

I've spent a day reading page 166's `length≤1` in the book **The Little Schemer**; there's the following code:

```
(((lambda (mk-length)
    (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
   (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) 0)
      (else (add1 
           ((mk-length eternity)
            (cdr l))))))))
 l)
```

where `l` is `(apples)` and `eternity` is as follows:

```
(define eternity 
  (lambda (x)
    (eternity x)))
```

Page 166 (4th ed.) states that:

> When we apply `mk-length` once, we get `length≤1`

And then

> Could we do this more than once?

But I do not know how to do this for getting `length≤2`?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323411/849891) of mine answers this question, for `length≤2` specifically (i.e. only 2, not more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `l` is `(apples oranges)`, then it will evaluate like this (note that `mk-length` is bound to the the `(lambda (mk-length) ...)` function itself:

```
(cond ((null? l) 0) 
      (else (add1 ((mk-length eternity) (cdr l)))))
==>
(add1 ((mk-length eternity) '(oranges)))
==>
(add1 ((lambda (l) (cond ((null? l) 0
                          (else (add1 ((eternity eternity) (cdr l))))))))
==>
(add1 (add1 ((eternity eternity) '())))
```

So here, after two steps, `eternity` ends up being applied, but what we want is for it to call `mk-length`. So in the original function, if we replace `eternity` by `mk-length`, then the last step I wrote will contain `(mk-length mk-length)` instead of `(eternity eternity)`, allowing the computation to proceed.

Comment: with `mk-length` instead of `eternity` this will be `length≤∞`, not `length≤2`.