# Little Schemer: write function that only supports lists of length ≤ 2

Tags: recursion, scheme, y-combinator, the-little-schemer, anonymous-recursion

In the book **The little schemer**, we find this function that only supports lists with length smaller than or equal to *1*:

```
 (((lambda (mk-length)                                  ; A.
      (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
      (lambda (l)
          (cond
              ((null? l ) 0)
              (else (add1 ((mk-length  eternity ) (cdr l))))))))
 '(1))
```

I want to study step by step, and want to write the similar function that supports only lists of length smaller than or equal to *2*.

Please, don't answer this question by offering code like:

```
(((lambda (mk-length)                                   ; B.
      (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
      (lambda (l)
          (cond
              ((null? l) 0 )
              (else (add1((mk-length mk-length) (cdr l))))))))
 '(a b c d))
```

because this function supports any length.

And I already know how to write function like this:

```
(((lambda (mk-length)                                   ; C.
      (mk-length
          (mk-length (mk-length eternity))))
  (lambda (length)
      (lambda (l)
          (cond
              ((null? l) 0)
              (else (add1 (length (cdr l))))))))
 '(1 2)) ;;
```

to achieve my goal. But this code is more than one step away from the first snippet.

Maybe, I should not change:

```
(lambda (mk-length)                                     ; D.
      (mk-length mk-length)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Also, you might find an answer in the answer (or linked questions) to: [Little Schemer: length0 and mk-length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19720833/1281433).  I won't flag as duplicate yet, because I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: I mean do the same thing as the 3th code I paste here. But should come from the 1th code's idea. which mean don't change 4th code in the 1th code.

Comment: Can you provide any insight as to *why* you're looking for this.  It's actually a non-trivial problem, because the point of this type of recursive exercise is that since the list is a recursive data structure, you need to handle just two cases:  the empty list, and the non-empty list.  The implementation for the <=1 case handles just the first case (the empty list).  You handle the =1 case by handling the non-empty case, but that lets you handle the =2, =3, etc., cases too, since they're handled in the same way as the =1 case.

Comment: 2th code just change `(mk-length  eternity )`  to `(mk-length  mk-length)` ,can achieve the any length. It is hard to think, so I want to implement a just `<=2` version. on 1th code's base

Comment: this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564013/how-to-do-this-length%E2%89%A41-more-than-once) but the answer there gives `length≤∞`, not `length≤2`.

Comment: @jiamo great question! it is important (in maths) to go carefully, being clear about each small step in the derivation (and the next step is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018651/little-schemer-why-wrap-mk-length-mk-length-into-a-function?rq=1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR:* `(mk-length A)` (inside the `cond` form) calculates the *`length`* function that works for lists of length *0* and will use `(A A)` to calculate the *`length`* function that will be used to work on the tail (i.e. the result of `(cdr ...)`) of the argument list.

---

Your first code snippet (`;A.`) works for lists of length *0* and *1* only. To make it work for *2* also, replacing

```
                               (mk-length eternity)               ; length≤1
```

with

```
                               (mk-length   ; (2)                 ; length≤2
                                  (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)))
```

works.

(NB: `(mk-length eternity)` itself calculates `length≤0`, but the overall function becomes `length≤1`; *this* is what all the further `length≤i` comments refer to.)

Looking closely at

```
     (((lambda (mk-length)
          (mk-length mk-length))            
      (lambda (mk-length)                   ; (1)
          (lambda (l)                       
              (cond
                  ((null? l ) 0)
                  (else (add1 ((mk-length   ; (2)                 ; length≤2
                                  (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)) )
                               (cdr l))))))))
     '(1 2))
```

we can see that the result of `(mk-length ...)` at `;(2)` is used to process `(cdr l)`, while the **`argument`** to `mk-length` at `;(2)` will replace `mk-length` in that call when processing the `(cddr l)`.

If `(mk-length eternity)` is used (as in your first code),  `(cdr l)` gets processed OK but `((eternity eternity) (cddr l))` naturally fails.

If `(mk-length (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)))` is used, `(cdr l)` gets processed OK and then `((lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)) (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity))) = (mk-length eternity)` is used to process `(cddr l)` which is also OK (so, length *2* is handled correctly), and then `((eternity eternity) (cdddr l))` naturally fails (for lengths *3* and up).

Thus to process the lists of up to three elements,

```
                              ((mk-length   ; (2)                 ; length≤3
                                  (lambda (x) (mk-length 
                                                (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)))) )
```

can be used:

```
    (define (eternity x) (- 1))    ; to get an error instead of looping

    (((lambda (mk-length)
          (mk-length mk-length))
      (lambda (mk-length)
          (lambda (l)
              (cond
                  ((null? l ) 0)
                  (else (add1 ((mk-length   ; (2)                 ; length≤3
                                  (lambda (x) (mk-length
                                               (lambda (x) (mk-length eternity)))) )
                               (cdr l))))))))

      '(1 2 3))        ; => 3

    ; ...........
    ; '(1 2 3 4))      ; => **error**
```

As you correctly surmised, *this* is the interim step on the way to using

```
                     (mk-length (lambda (x) (mk-length x)))   ; (2)       ; length≤∞
```

which turns, on the processing of the next element of the list into

```
                     ((lambda (x) (mk-length x)) (lambda (x) (mk-length x)))
    =
                     (mk-length (lambda (x) (mk-length x)))
```

and thus works for *every* list, whatever its length is.

And by eta-conversion this is just `(mk-length mk-length)`.

Comment: This answer was worth looking at, for me, indeed. =) Thanks for the answer itself and for notifying me about it!

Comment: @FilippW. you're welcome, and thanks for the impetus to do this (i.e. your answers and edits to this cluster of problems). Re: your edit, those weren't typos. I meant the initial `l`, so the call `(... (cdr l))` in the second iteration, when this `l` is actually `(cdr l)` for the *original* `l`, is `(.... (cddr l))`. And it's `(cdddr l)` in the third. it's a little sloppy and confusing, but just using `(cdr l)` won't do either. I'll think of somehow clarifying this thing, later. thanks!

Comment: Oh, my bad I didn't grasped it at once. Thanks for the explanation, though!

Answer (score 2):

Lists in Lisp (Scheme, Common Lisp, etc.) are built out of cons cells and a special (the empty list).  That, whenever you have something that is a list, it is *either*:

- The empty list **()**
- A cons cell (also called a pair) where the **car** of the pair is the first element of the list and the **cdr** of the pair is the rest of the list.

Because there are two types of lists, recursive algorithms on lists usually answer just two questions:

- What is the result for the empty list?
- What is the result for rest of the list and how is that turned into the result for the whole list?

For *length*, this means:

- The length of the empty list is 0.
- When the length of the *rest* of the list is *n*, the length of the whole list is *n + 1*.

The type of solution presented in *The Little Schemer* first develops a solution that answers the first case, which means that it works for lists of length ≤0.  As soon as you have a solution that handles both cases (correctly), you have a solution that works for lists of any length.  There's no real incremental solution that would extend the function to work for lists of length ≤2.

You *could*, I suppose, do something like:

```
 (((lambda (mk-length)
      (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
      (lambda (l)
          (cond
              ((null? l ) 0)
              (else 1)))))
```

That would work for lists of length 0 and lists of length 1, and it would be incorrect for all other lists, but it would return 1 for all other lists.  Unless you change the structure of the recursion, I think that's really the best you can do.  If you're willing to change the structure of the recursion, you *could* do:

```
 (((lambda (mk-length)
      (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
      (lambda (l)
          (cond
              ((null? l) 0)
              ((null? (cdr l)) 1)
              (else (add1 ((mk-length  eternity ) (cdr l))))))))
```

but you *really* shouldn't take this approach, because now you're processing lists in three different cases instead of two, which is (almost) never what you want to do.

### A translation to Python

> *Can this thinking rewrite by python or something process language? It is still hard to image a auto created fun in recurse.*

The same principle works in Python, or any language that supports higher-order functions.  It's more idiomatic in Python to locally define the function and then call it, rather than calling a lambda expression directly, so this may be more readable for you:

```py
def length(l):
    def driver(recurse):
        "Returns the result of calling `recurse` with itself."
        return recurse(recurse);
    def zeroForEmptyListOrElseOnePlusRecurse(recurse):
        """Returns a function that returns 0 if its input is the
        empty list, or else returns one plus whatever calling 
        `recurse(recurse)` with the tail of the list returns."""
        def length(l):
            """Returns 0 if l is the empty list, and one plus
            the results of `(recurse(recurse))(l)` otherwise."""
            if l == []:
                return 0;
            else:
                _, *rest = l
                return 1+(recurse(recurse))(rest)
        return length
    return (driver(zeroForEmptyListOrElseOnePlusRecurse))(l)
```

```
print(length([1,2,3])) # 3
print(length([1,2]))   # 2
print(length([1]))     # 1
print(length([]))      # 0
```

Comment: I think you already answer my question!  Can you explain more about how using your answer to get the code `(mk-length mk-length)` to work for any lenght of list? Substituting the `mk-length` to first lambda is easy to think, however it is hard to think re-substituting inside again. For me it is not nature to think about it. However it is easy for somebody else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you replace `(mk-length eternity)` with `(mk-length mk-length)` in my answer, it should work.  But you'll still have a redundant clause in your cond.

Comment: May be i am asking how `mk-length` in `(add1 ((mk-lenght mk-lenght) (cdr l))` works? Can this thinking rewrite by python or something process language? It is still hard to image a  auto created fun in recurse.

Comment: @jiamo I've added a Python translation.