# Little Schemer: why wrap (mk-length mk-length) into a function?

Tags: recursion, scheme, y-combinator, the-little-schemer, anonymous-recursion

In [The Little Schemer book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC), in Chapter 9, while building a `length` function for arbitrary long input, the following is suggested (on [pages 170-171](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false)), that in the following code snippet (from [page 168](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q&f=false) itself):

```
((lambda (mk-length)
   (mk-length mk-length))                      
 (lambda (mk-length)
   ((lambda (length)                           
      (lambda (l)
        (cond
          ((null? l) 0)
          (else (add1 (length (cdr l)))))))   
    (mk-length mk-length))))
```

the part `(mk-length mk-length)`, will never return and will be infinitely applying itself to itself:

> Because we just keep applying `mk-length` to itself again and again and again...

and

> But now that we have extracted `(mk-length mk-length)` from the function that makes `length` it does not return a function anymore.

Now, to cure this the book suggest:

> Turn the application of `mk-length` to itself in our last correct version of `length` into a function.

Like, so:

```
((lambda (mk-length)
   (mk-length mk-length))
 (lambda (mk-length)
   ((lambda (length)
     (lambda (l)
       (cond
         ((null? l) 0 )
         (else 
           (add1 (length (cdr l)))))))
   (lambda (x)
     ((mk-length mk-length) x)))))
```

What I get puzzled by is:

1. If `(mk-length mk-length)`

   > does not return a function

   how we can apply the result of `(mk-length mk-length)` to something, as if it is a function?

   ```
   (lambda (x)
     ((mk-length mk-length) x))
   ```
2. How wrapping `(mk-length mk-length)` into a function solves the 'never returning' (i.e. infinite recursion) problem? My understanding is, that in:

   ```
   (lambda (x)
     ((mk-length mk-length) x))
   ```

`x` will just be passed to infinitely recursive function, which never returns.

Comment: It is the [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator).

Comment: It's not infinite recursion. Each step uses `(cdr l)` as the argument, and it stops when that becomes null.

Comment: Why do you think `(mk-length mk-length)` doesn't return a function? The value of `mk-length` is the second lambda-expression, and it returns `(lambda (l) ...)`, which is a function.

Comment: cf. [Y combinator discussion in “The Little Schemer”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10499514/849891) which discusses the same piece of code. Your question is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864862/849891) there.

Comment: @DanD. still not a combinator though at that point, just getting ever so closer to it. it becomes combinator when the `(lambda (l) ...)` gets abstracted away.

Comment: There is a great [post by Mike Vanier](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) with the **detailed** explanation on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably copied the wrong code snippet, the one before that which you actually talk about. The first code you've shown is totally fine. What loops is, rather, this one:

```
   ((lambda (mk-length)
      (mk-length mk-length))                      ; (1)
    (lambda (mk-length)
      ((lambda (length)                           ; (2)
         (lambda (l)
           (cond
             ((null? l) 0)
             (else (add1 (length (cdr l)))))))    ; (4)
       (mk-length mk-length))))                   ; (3)
```

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864862/849891): the application `(1)` triggers the application `(2)` which triggers the application `(3)` *right away*, which is equivalent to `(1)`! Thus, the looping.

Wrapping it in a lambda (aka *eta-expansion*) delays the application `(3)` until the call to the constructed `length` is made in `(4)`, and that's fully OK (you copied this with some typos as well):

```
   ((lambda (mk-length)
      (mk-length mk-length))                      ; (1)
    (lambda (mk-length)                                   ; (5)
      ((lambda (length)                           ; (2)
         (lambda (l)
           (cond
             ((null? l) 0)
             (else (add1 (length (cdr l)))))))    ; (4)
       (lambda (x)                                ; (3)
         (mk-length mk-length) x))))
```

`(3)` is a lambda expression now, not an application. Evaluating this lambda expression produces an anonymous function. This lambda function *will* perform the application `(mk-length mk-length)` *later*, when `length` is called.

*(a longer explanation:)* 
`(3)` just returns the lambda function right away which gets bound to `length`, and `(lambda (l) ...)` is happily returned such that when *that* `(lambda (l) ...)` *will* be applied to some list, possibly causing this `length`<sup>1</sup> to be called in `(4)`, only *then* the application `(mk-length mk-length)` inside the lambda `(3)` will actually be performed — giving us the new `(lambda (l) ...)` anonymous function eventually, which will get applied to the `(cdr l)` there.

<sup>1</sup>`length` is `(lambda (x) ((mk-length mk-length) x))` which means that `(length (cdr l))` is the same as `((mk-length mk-length) (cdr l))` (with `mk-length` bound to the whole lambda-expression `(5)`), and eventually, `((lambda (l) ...) (cdr l))`.

nina

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and pointing out my typos and 'mis-copings' (I believe I've corrected them, now).

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
(mk-length mk-length)
```

will call `mk-length` only once.

If `mk-length` happens to call it-self, then the body of `mk-length` will
be evaluated again — but `mk-length` doesn't always call itself.

As to why — notice that no function in your expression has been named using `define`. All function expressions use `lambda` which introduce an anonymous function.

The example shows that even though only anonymous functions are used, it is possible to write recursive functions. Instead of naming the function directly (using `define`), the function is passed as argument to another function — and that function has names for its arguments.